# Whether knower disappears automatically after doer disappeared?

Tags: theravada

Did   meditation; when concentration  on the  breath at the tip of the  nose  suddenly  controller has disappeared and cittarupa came without  control.Is it a stage  that knower  and doer disappeared?after the experience  feel like no self at that time.

Answer (score 2):

> *Did meditation; when concentration on the breath at the tip of the nose suddenly controller has disappeared and cittarupa came without
>   control.*

Cittarupa always functions by itself. The idea of a "controller" is an illusion created by delusion, ignorance, clinging & craving.

> *Is it a stage that knower and doer disappeared? after the experience feel like no self at that time.*

Yes. When the sense of knower & doer disappear, this is insight into anatta (not-self) of the five aggregates. The five aggregates operate on their own, without a self controlling them.

Comment: Is this the place where called it as non occurrence?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, awareness of the knower and doer disappear only during the meditative state of samadhi, including the experience of sunyata in samadhi. But there are many states of samadhi. They disappear together in any case. In the Theravadin tradition the experience of the knower remains present during vipassana or insight meditation and also during Nibbana. In Theravadin Buddhism, insight into no-self is a relative truth and not an experience of samadhi. In Mahayana Buddhism, the experience of no-self occurs only during the experience of sunyata, making no-self an absolute truth. Nibbana and sunyata are not the same thing.

Ordinarily, “concentration on the breath at the tip of the nose” is a part of vipassana practice. However, depending upon one’s karma, a person can easily slip into a state of full samadhi.

You seem to be mixing the Theravadin and Mahayana teachings, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha tried to show us the inherent unsatisfactoriness of all that constitutes a human being, so that we make real effort to get out of the wheel of birth and death. We have to understand that there is no individual who owns body, feeling, perception, thought and consciousness. That is the most difficult aspect of the Buddha’s teaching. Difficult to conceptualize and even more difficult to experience. Without meditation, it will remain an intellectual exercise. Even in meditation only if you are a’Sotapanna’ / Stream Entrant, will you l get to understand that there is the deed, but no doer.